# ast.Num or visit_Num method in python return a wrong sign number of node

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I'am using built in module AST (Abstract Syntax Tress) to manually parse a expression instead using Eval, Exec or Compile. In python 2 is perfectly work fine. However in python 3, it take 3 process of node before parsing the expression and the result is wrong cause it's supposed to be negative but it's returning a positive value.

python 2

```
def test(string_value):
    parse_expression = ast.parse(string_value)
    node = parse_expression.body
    
    for per in node:
        
        # return <_ast.Expr object at 0x7fa695c78510>
        print(per)
        
        # return <_ast.Num object at 0x7ff4b0b1de50>
        print(per.value)
        
        # return -890
        print(per.value.n)

        pass
    pass

test("-890")
```

Python 3

```
import ast

def test(string_value):
    parse_expression = ast.parse(string_value)
    node = parse_expression.body
    
    for per in node:
        # return <_ast.Expr object at 0x7fe6a0ce34c0>
        print(per)
        
        #return <_ast.UnaryOp object at 0x7f0b92941790>
        print(per.value)
        
        # ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_fields', 'col_offset', 'end_col_offset', 'end_lineno', 'lineno', 'op', 'operand']
        
        print(dir(per.value))
        
        
        print(per.value.col_offset) #0
        print(per.value.end_col_offset) #4
        print(per.value.end_lineno) #1
        print(per.value.lineno) #1
        print(per.value.op) # <_ast.USub object at 0x7f055c489610>
        print(per.value.operand) #<_ast.Constant object at 0x7f055c45d8e0>
        
        # ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_fields']
        
        print(dir(per.value.op))
        
        # ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_fields', 'col_offset', 'end_col_offset', 'end_lineno', 'kind', 'lineno', 'n', 's', 'value']
        
        print(dir(per.value.operand))
        
        print(per.value.operand.col_offset) #1
        print(per.value.operand.end_col_offset) #4
        print(per.value.operand.end_lineno) #1
        print(per.value.operand.kind) #None
        print(per.value.operand.lineno) #1
        
        # it's return a postive value instead negative value
        
        print(per.value.operand.n) #890
        print(per.value.operand.s) #890
        print(per.value.operand.value) #890
        
        # return -890
        # print(per.value.n)
        
        pass
    pass

test("-890")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, as in most languages, `-890` is an expression, not a literal number. The literal number is `890` and the unary minus operator is applied to that literal.

That technique avoids a grammatical problem. Literals are identified by a tokenizer, and then passed to the parser. If the tokenizer considered `-` to be part of the literal, then `a-890` would be divided into two tokens, the identifier `a` and the literal number `-890`. But that's not what the input means; clearly, `-` should be handled as the `minus` operator, not part of the number. Since tokenising happens first, it's independent of the syntax, so the tokeniser has to always return `-` as an operator, and that's what it does.

Often language processors might later "fold" constant subexpressions into precomputed values, turning the expresion `- 890` into a constant number. In Python 3, the AST module doesn't do that -- it's just a parser.

In both Python 2 and Python 3, constant folding does seem to happen before the parsed expression is turned into byte code:

```py
>>> # This is Python 3 but Python 2 produces a very similar result.
>>> import dis
>>> def minus890():
...   return -890
...
>>> def other_minus890():
...   return (7 * 120 + 50) * -1
...
>>> # Both functions compiled into exactly the same byte code:
>>> dis.dis(minus890)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-890)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(other_minus890())
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-890)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```